# How to find a multiline partial regex match in multiple files?

Tags: regex, search, grep, file-search

I have a bunch of files. Every file can contain one or more matches for the following regex pattern:

```
(foo)([\s\S]+)(bar)
```

The matches can contain line breaks / multiple lines.

I want to extract all occurrences of the matching group `$2` to a file or print them to the console.

I tried that with `grep`, but it didn't work, since `grep` processes the text line-wise.

Summary:

So, what I need is following:

- Search in multiple files.
- RegEx search.
- Extracting of a specific matching group.

Is there a tool (for GUI or CLI), that meets this requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do the job with a Perl one-liner.
The following code processes files of the current directory that have a names beginning with `file`, you have to adapt according to the files you want to process.

```bsh
perl -ane 'if (/foo/.../bar/) {print $_ unless /foo|bar/}' file*
```

**explanation:**

```perl
if (/foo/.../bar/) {    # if the current line is between foo and bar (included)
    print $_                # print the current line
        unless /foo|bar/        # unless it matches foo or bar
}                       # endif
```